# Trouble putting scripts in order

Tags: javascript, html

I’ve run into trouble trying to place the scripts and css in the right order. If I put my own script before the leaflet.js script I get this error message from the console: L is not defined. But, if I put it after the leaflet.js script I get this message in the console: Map container not found. What am doing wrong?

```
<!--Own-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
<!--Leaflet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js" ></script>
<!--jQuery-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is too hard to tell how exactly you should structure it without knowing what is in your files, but as the code will get executed top to bottom so an example would be that you should have ```//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js``` above ```js/main.js``` if this file uses jquery. You should put your css first and then your script files

Answer (score 0):

"Map container not found" may mean that the HTML you are referencing in your script hasn't been created when the script executes.

Best practice is to place script tags at the end of the body, and wrap initialization calls in a:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // your code here
} );
```